# What is correct way to return jwt token after OAuth authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've integrated OAuth 2.0 (Google) into my application, and I have a question about how to return the JWT token for future requests from the user.

I have this AuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                      Authentication authentication)
          throws IOException, ServletException {
    OidcUser oauthUser = (OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

    String firstName = oauthUser.getAttribute("given_name");
    String lastName = oauthUser.getAttribute("family_name");
    String email = oauthUser.getAttribute("email");

    if (!userRepository.existsUserByEmail(email)){
      user creation logic
    }
    
    response.sendRedirect("/");
  }
}
```

Should I generate tokens directly in this method, or should I redirect to a REST endpoint that will return the tokens? If I choose the latter, how can the front end catch them?

Is there a way to return access and refresh tokens to the front end? And how can the front end catch them if the OAuth login is initiated by a special link rather than a request from the front end?

Comment: you should never hand out JWT tokens to browsers, you keep the token in the backend and issue a cookie to the frontend. When you later make a request the cookie is also supplied, you send it through a proxy that will exchange the cookie for a jwt if you are calling a resource server. This is how the OIDC spec works. Google does not support resource servers, so you authenticate with google, then your server returns a cookie, then you use the cookie against your server.